# AttributeError: 'TestHandler' object has no attribute 'model' in django piston

Tags: python, django, django-piston

This is a test.py file that tries to send data to the api endpoint:

```
import os
import requests


import uuid


def get_uid():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())
oauth_consumer_key = 'abcd'
oauth_signature = 'efgh'

oauth_signature_method = 'PLAINTEXT'
oauth_timestamp ='132798314211'
oauth_nonce = get_uid() + "aa"

oauth_token_secret = ""
x_auth_mode = 'client_auth'
x_auth_username = ''
x_auth_password = ''
userid = ''

instagram_id = "asdas"
instagram_token = "asdas"

params = {

            'oauth_consumer_key':oauth_consumer_key,
            'oauth_signature':oauth_signature,
            'oauth_signature_method':oauth_signature_method,
            'oauth_timestamp': oauth_timestamp,
            'oauth_nonce': get_uid(),
            'instagram_id' : instagram_id,
            'instagram_token':instagram_token,            
            }

url = 'http://localhost:8000/instagram/signin/'
data = {'instagram_id':instagram_id,'instagram_token':instagram_token}

r = requests.post(url,params)

print r.content
```

This is my Testhandler:

```
class TestHandler(AnonymousBaseHandler):



    def read(self,request,action=None):

        """Get request to get the instagram code
        """
        print action

        if action == "signin":
            return "hello121"
            #self.instagram_signin(request)




    def instagram_signin(self,request):
        """
            Check if the instagram user exists in the database
        """
        return "Yes!"
```

Yes, as basic as that and it returns an error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_piston-0.3dev-py2.7.egg/piston/handler.py", line 105, in create
    except self.model.DoesNotExist:

AttributeError: 'TestHandler' object has no attribute 'model'
```

The app is registered in settings.py. I have done syncdb multiple times. Restarted server. Restarted system and still can't get this figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the example](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#anonymous-resources) was written:

```
class AnonymousBlogpostHandler(AnonymousBaseHandler):
    model = Blogpost
    fields = ('title', 'content')
```

You missed `model`.